# Different Generators of Homology group: Geometric meanings

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

For Homology, I am aware that one can choose different generators that generate the same homology group.

Geometrically, is there a meaning to the different generators? What do they represent?

Thanks.

Comment: The comment I made on your last question applies to this, too: a cycle defines a map from a pseudomanifold, and two cycles are equivalent (define the same element in homology) if these are bordant through some pseudomanifold.